# Sum data across multiple sheets using index match and indirect

Tags: excel, indexing, sum, match

I have multiple tabs with account balances within one excel spreadsheet. All sheets are set up exactly the same. I would like to sum the end of month account balances across all sheets. I would use sumifs but the difficulty is that there can be more than one balance data for the same day in which case I would need the formula to take the last one (furthest down in the column where the balances are held). I have tried index match with indirect as follows:

`{SUM(INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&Sheets&"'!"&"$AJ$5:$AJ$250"),MATCH(C$2,INDIRECT("'"&Sheets&"'!"&"$B$5:$B$250"),0)))}`

Named range "Sheets" holds the names of all tabs that I need the sum to work.

`AJ$5:$AJ$250` is where the balances are within the "Sheets".

`B$5:$B$250` is where the balance dates are within the "Sheets".

C$2 (row 2) is the end of month criteria on the summary sheet based on which I would like to find and sum the balances.

The above formula only picks up the value from the first sheet within the "Sheets" named range.

Would appreciate help how to correct.

Comment: How many cells do you need from each spreadsheet? I mean, do you only need the latest balance (1 cell, then)? I am assuming each spreadsheet represents a month and you only need the latest value of each spreadsheet.

Comment: Each sheet represents a current account with years long data. For each month on the summary spreadsheet I need the sum of the corresponding month end balances from each sheet (account). In case there are more than one balances corresponding to a month end date on one of the sheets (accounts) the formula should take the last one (furthest down).

Comment: I would recommend you to make it work for one spreadsheet first, then make it more general. 
If I understood it right, the xlookup can handle your need to get the latest balance: =XLOOKUP(C$2,Sheet1!$B$5:$B$250,Sheet1!$AJ$5:$AJ$250,,,-1)

The argument "-1" at the end means the search will start from the botton. 


If you have more information that can help me find the best formula for you (for example a chunk working), please let me know.

Comment: Actually, the formula I pasted in the description works if I make at an array, however it only picks up the value from the first sheet from the "Sheets" named range. Any idea why? (I have no issues creating a formula that works for only one sheet by the way)

Comment: Yes, your formula is creating a "row vector". If you place your array onto several cells in a row, you will see the value for each spreadsheet. That means the sum is not working the way you want on the formula. If you delete the sum, the result is going to be the same vector. The easiest solution? Just make the sum out of the formula. The complex solution? This link might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/q/61797451/8060081

Comment: Thank you. I'll have a close look on the complex solution. I have another near solution in the meantime. ```{SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(INDIRECT("'"&Sheets&"'!"&"$AE$5:$AE$25000"),INDIRECT("'"&Sheets&"'!"&"$B$5:$B$25000"),"="&C$2))}``` works. The only issue is it picks up ALL balances that fall on the date in cell C2 on the summary tab. If there was a way to force SUMIFS to only pick up the last data for the date in cell C2 that would make the formula perfect. Is there any way this can be done?